# What's the most straightforward way of painting RGBA data into a view on Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, image, macos

Long story short, every 60<sup>th</sup> of a second I have a relatively small buffer (256x240) of RGBA data (8 bits per component, 4 bytes per pixel) that is refreshed with new data, and I want to display it (I guess inside an `NSView`, but anything is welcome). What's the most straightforward way to do it? Building a `CGImageRef` from a `CGBitmapContext` to write it to the `CGContextRef` obtained from the `NSGraphicsContext` seems a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Building a CGImageRef from a CGBitmapContext to write it to the CGContextRef obtained from the NSGraphicsContext seems a bit convoluted.

It is. Specifically, the “bit” is CGBitmapContext; you don't need that if you already have raster data to create an image from. Just [create the image](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreate), and then draw it into the CGContext you got from the current NSGraphicsContext.

Comment: Well, the CGBitmapContext bit gets replaced by a CGDataProvider bit. I suppose it's more efficient, but it's not really saving any line of code.

Comment: It's only one line of code to create a data provider from data you already have. For NS/CFData objects: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData For bare data buffers: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGDataProviderCreateWithData